# RxSwift: Combining different types of observables and mapping result

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I am pretty new to RxSwift and stuck in creating a sequence.

I have 3 observables (isChanged, updatedValue, savedValue).
If form value isChanged I want to use updatedValue otherwise savedValue.
I tried using .combineLatest as

```
Observable.combineLatest( isChanged, updatedValue, savedValue,
resultSelector: {isChanged, updatedValue, savedValue in
   print ("\(isChanged), \(updatedValue), \(savedValue)")
 }.observeOn(MainSchedular.instance)
  .subscribe()
  .disposed(by: bag)
```

I want to use updatedValue only if isChanged flag is changed otherwise always use savedValue.

I tried using flatMapLatest as well but I am struggling with syntax too. Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: sounds like you just need `return isChanged ? updatedValue : savedValue`.

Comment: If the `updatedValue` stream would send values only when the value changes, then you'd need to observe only that one.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. updatedValue is changed with every key strike, isChanged is called only when update button is tapped while savedValue is orignal value.
Thing is , once value is updated, flag is true, next time this stream picks up true again if any of the other observable value is changed and it messes up the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment describes a different use-case than what the question describes...

> updatedValue is changed with every key strike, isChanged is called only when update button is tapped while savedValue is orignal value.

The above implies that you want something like:

```
func example<Value>(savedValue: Value, isChanged: Observable<Void>, updatedValue: Observable<Value>) -> Observable<Value> {
    isChanged
        .withLatestFrom(updatedValue)
        .startWith(savedValue)
}
```

The above will emit the `savedValue`, then emit whatever was last emitted by `updatedValue` every time `isChanged` emits. I suggest you change the name of `isChanged` to something else since it isn't a Bool.

Meanwhile, the question implies that you want something more like:

```
func exampleʹ<Value>(savedValue: Value, isChanged: Observable<Bool>, updatedValue: Observable<Value>) -> Observable<Value> {
    isChanged
        .withLatestFrom(updatedValue) { $0 ? savedValue : $1 }
}
```

The above will also emit a value every time `isChanged` emits a value. It will emit `savedValue` whenever `isChanged` emits false and `updatedValue` whenever `isChanged` emits true.

---

If `savedValue` is an Observable (maybe from a network request or a DB get) then the code would look more like this:

```
func example<Value>(isChanged: Observable<Void>, savedValue: Observable<Value>, updatedValue: Observable<Value>) -> Observable<Value> {
    savedValue
        .concat(
            isChanged.withLatestFrom(updatedValue)
        )
}

func exampleʹ<Value>(isChanged: Observable<Bool>, savedValue: Observable<Value>, updatedValue: Observable<Value>) -> Observable<Value> {
    isChanged
        .withLatestFrom(Observable.combineLatest(savedValue, updatedValue)) { $0 ? $1.0 : $1.1 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps @Danie
l.isChanged
        .withLatestFrom(updatedValue) I needed this operator